# CountDownTimer service

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer

Im trying to make a countdown timer run in the background of my activity, it needs to run constantly until it finishes, but not sure how to make it work with a service.  I also need to update the display on my main activity

Comment: We need to see some code. Why are you using a service? They are a battery drain and there are other solutions but it depends on the context and you might have a valid reason.

Comment: Im using it as a reminder for a application to use while performing a task, Going to have it give alerts when steps are needed, but want it to keep going no matter what so they can go to other apps, or other pages

Comment: So basically there is a process that has to keep going 100% of the time and will be doing something useful all the time. If this process sits there and does nothing but count then you are just wasting the user's battery needlessly. A good example for use of a service is to monitor audio levels. A bad example is to post reminders every x seconds. You could use the AlarmManager for that.

Comment: Ok, but can I update a view to have a countdown clock as well, they need to see how much time is remaining, and its only going to be running for about an hour at a time

Comment: Have you seen http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html this seems a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, not all services run 100% of the time. *Nothing* is a battery drain unless it's executing at 100%. If you look at the actual battery consumption of an Android device, you'll see that the largest percentage comes from the screen. The next comes from radios. Running a process costs very little.

You can use an IntentService to fire off an alarm at regular intervals. The service can send intents to itself. Have one intent action to start the service, and one to turn off the alarm. Make a third action for resetting the alarm.

To start the service, send a "start" intent to the IntentService using startService(intent). This should trigger a method that creates an intent with action "cycle", puts the intent in a PendingIntent, and schedules a repeating alarm with AlarmManager.setRepeating().

After the interval that you set for the alarm, the AlarmManager will take the "cycle" intent out of the PendingIntent and send it back to your service. Your service should handle "cycle" by rebuilding the PendingIntent and restarting the alarm. This goes on indefinitely. You can put anything else you want to do when the alarm goes off in the handling for the "cycle" action.

When you want the alarm to stop, send the "stop" intent. In response, your service should cancel the alarm by reconstructing the PendingIntent and then calling AlarmManager.cancel().

Notes: The main entry point for an IntentService is onHandleIntent(). You call everything else from there. When that method finishes, the service goes inactive until it receives another intent. The only place you can "see" it is in cached processes. Once you stop the alarm, the system will eventually figure out that the service isn't being used, and garbage-collect it.

Services are the way to do background work. I suppose you can run some AsyncTask or a thread, but you still want to run them in a Service, otherwise you've linked them to something that's running in the foreground. If the task doesn't need to interact with the user, particularly if it can work asynchronously to your activity, then use a service.

Comment: This is close to what Ive been trying to do, but cant figure out the service code, any chance you could post an example, or a link to one, thanks

Comment: So didnt end up using service, but scheduled a series of alarms for when i needed them using the AlarmManager.  Works for what I need